# continuous delivery not working when using below YAML

Tags: azure, azure-devops

We have Azure DevOps Repo, where want to run the pipline as soon as the PR is complete i.e we merge the changes We are using below script:

```
# Define trigger for the pipeline
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - Development
      - QualityAssurance
      - Production
  paths:
    include:
      - '*'
variables:
- group: 'GroupNames'

# Define stages for Dev, QA, and Prod
stages:
  - stage: Development
    displayName: 'Dev'
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/Development'))
    jobs:
      - template: ./deploy-files-template.yaml
        parameters:
          azureSubscription: 'xxx'
          poolname: 'Dev-Ubuntu-20.04'
          vargroup: 'GroupNames'
          inlineScript: 'az storage blob upload-batch -d "$(abcabc)" --account-name "$(abcabc)" -s "$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/repos/" --account-key "$(abcabc)" --overwrite'


  - stage: QualityAssurance
    displayName: 'QA'
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/pull/*/merge'), eq(variables['System.PullRequest.TargetBranch'], 'refs/heads/QualityAssurance'))
    jobs:
      - template: ./deploy-files-template.yaml
        parameters:
          azureSubscription: 'xxx'
          poolname: 'QA-Ubuntu-20.04'
          vargroup: 'QNames'
          inlineScript: 'az storage blob upload-batch -d "$(abcabc)" --account-name "$(abcabc)" -s "$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/repos/" --account-key "$(abcabc)" --overwrite'
```

What do we need to do if we want to run the pipeline as soon as a PR is completed,

We tried using **pr:** but it does not seems to work

It skips the stages after completing the PR.

[image]
can some suggest please?

Answer (score 0):

Add the merge target branch to the `branches` section of your `trigger`.

Comment: Could you please elaborate

Comment: What do you need elaboration on? If you want a branch to trigger when a merge is made to it, add the branch to the `trigger` section.

Comment: I have already did that as you can see but it wont work

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are merging to one of the given branches `Development`, `QualityAssurance`, `Production`,
The configuration given seems correct, but there are couple things to double-check:

1. Go to YAML edit -> 3 dots -> Triggers. It opens up a visual editor for continuous integration. Make sure it is not set to override your YAML triggers.
2. Does not seem like you need the Path property if you want to include all paths anyways, you can try removing it.

Answer (score 0):

> We tried using pr: but it does not seems to work

It will not work, you should use branch policies: [Build validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#build-validation)

Check the documentation: [pr definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/pr?view=azure-pipelines)

> YAML PR triggers are supported only in GitHub and Bitbucket Cloud. If
> you use Azure Repos Git, you can configure a branch policy for build
> validation to trigger your build pipeline for validation.

---

> It skips the stages after completing the PR.

It skips because your source branch is different of:

```
condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/Development'))
```

You may press here and check your `Build.SourceBranch` validation step:

[image]